# Discord.py Commands Unresponsive

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot with a simple function of creating a channel, but it is unsuccessful.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import discord
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$',intents=intents)
guild = discord.Guild

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("I'm in as " + str(client.user))

@bot.command(name = "hack")
async def court_create(ctx, msg): 
    print("Received: $hack") #output to console
    channel_name = "hack-" + str(msg)
    await ctx.send(channel_name) #output to channel
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name = channel_name)


keep_alive()
Token = os.environ['Token']
client.run(Token)
```

Note that for debugging, I added two lines so that when it receives the command, it prints out to both the console and the channel. However, when I typed `$hack 123` into the channel, it did nothing, not even outputting `Received: $hack`. Any ideas about this?
Bot has manage channel permission.

Comment: Is the `on_ready` print statement working?

Comment: Yes. Everything else is working (I have a command using the old message.content method).

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command(name = "hack")
async def court_create(ctx, msg):
```

The name in `bot.command` and the name of the function are two completely different names. It only reads what the function name is. If you want to add `hack` as another method of using the command you can use the `aliases` argument in `bot.command()`

Example:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["hack"])
async def court_create(ctx, msg):
```

Comment: I changed the function name to `hack`, but still nothing happens.

Comment: There could be a few issues, `on_message` events could cause commands to stop working if you don't put `bot.process_commands(message)` you may be getting an error but your error handler may be eating the traceback. You may want to check if one of those issues is in your code